Common property about the intersection of all structures containing a subset B being the structure generated by B.
To what other structures does this generalize?
The intersection of all subgroups containing a subset $ $ $S$ $ $ is $ $ $<S>$ $ $.
The intersection of all ring ideals containing a subset $ $ $S$ $ $ is $ $ $<S>$ $ $.
The intersection of all topologies containing a basis $ $ $B$ $ $ is $ $ $<B>$ $ $.
The intersection of all vector spaces containing a subset $ $ $S$ $ $ is $ $ $<S>$ $ $
And so on. All of these are the smallest structure containing the other. I have seen this pattern popping up in my classes a lot recently, but bear in mind I have NOT taken universal algebra or anything of the sort, only vaguely read some things. It reminds of Noether's 4 isomorphism theorems, which generalize to many algebraic structures. I suppose this generalizes to any other type of structure in which the intersection is also one such stucture.

The ideal case (universal property of ideal gcd = sum) is discussed here and its links. The others are analogous.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_operator and use site search please (also to those who might answer). Quite sure this is a duplicate.

I will also remove the misused tag "universal property". Please check tag descriptions if you are unsure. And I change the title slightly to avoid misunderstandings (which apparently have already happened).

I don't know how much this answers your question but the pattern here is the adjoint functor theorem: see here.
